# Finding an Alternating Projection for a more Complicated Knot

Tags: knot-theory

So lately, I have been going through Colin Adams "The Knot Book" as I recently stumbled upon the intriguing world of knot theory. My only complaint with the book is that I believe it would be nice to have a bit more guidance with some of the exercises.

In any case, I have been struggling with exercise 3.4 shown here.
This is the question:

[image]

I understand how to get the unknotting number. I can't get the alternating projection. Whenever I do a series of Reidemeister moves, the knot gets even more convoluted and seemingly farther away from an alternating projection. I imagined the solution to be much more efficient than what I've been doing.

If I need to edit my post to make it more in line with the rules here or to clarify something, please do let me know. I'm very new here.

I really appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Comment: I would advise against doing a single Reidemeister move at a time. For instance, I would take whole tangles and move them.  This obviously has risks of doing too much and making a mistake, but to do every R move would be a lot worse, in my opinion.  Also, for a hint here specifically, if you know about 2-bridge (sometimes called rational) knots and the way we generally draw them, that could help.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. In the book, this exercise is meant to be done before the section on 2-bridge knots, so I believe it is possible to be completed with individual Reidemeister moves. Can you elaborate on moving whole tangles please? I don't see an advantage doing that over R. moves. I appreciate your response, @N.Owad

Comment: It looks to me like the two places where it is not alternating is between the $-a_3$ and $a_3$ tangles and the top strand to the left of the $-a_2$ tangle.  Well, if we slide all of the crossings in the $a_3$ tangle under that strand above it, that would take a lot of R moves.  But we can probably see how the knot would look afterwards even if we skip all the R moves.  This might be enough to make it alternating, but I am not sure.